# Efficient way to create a weighted graph with networkx where weights are intersection of appearances between reviewers identities?

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I am analyzing Amazon's reviews dataset, and I have, customers IDs, their reviews on different products, and products' identifiers as well.
The data can be represented by:

| Customer | Product | Review | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | .... |  |
| 1 | B | .... |  |
| 2 | A | .... |  |
| 2 | C | .... |  |

I want to create a weighted undirected graph using `networkx`, where each node would be a product, and the weights between nodes (products) would be the number of different customers that reviewed the two products.
The data is huge, so I was wondering if there is a feasible way to update the current weights of a network iteratively when going product by product.

Another desirable representation of this graph would be, for the example above,

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| B | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| C | 1 | 0 | 1 |

EDIT: Mistakenly wrote the `(A,C)=2`. Replaced it with 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
# cross-tabulate
v = pd.crosstab(df['Product'], df['Customer'])
# dot product for the number of customers who reviewed 2 products
v.dot(v.T)
Product  A  B  C
Product         
A        2  1  1
B        1  1  0
C        1  0  1
```